# Spiky corners with Graphics.DrawLines

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, gdi+

When I draw a sequence of points with Graphics.DrawLines, the corners of thick lines (in the example width 30) appear very spiky, like in the image below. The actual appearance of the corner spikes seems random. Using DrawCurve instead of DrawLines didn't help.

[image]

I checked if the point sequence contains adjacent identical points in the hope that it might just be a mathematical ill-definedness of the line. But no, the first list shows the points near the top right corner, the second list shows the points near the end of the stroke at the bottom right.

[image]

[image]

```
public class Stroke
{
    Pen pen;
    List<Point> points;

    public readonly Color Color;
    public readonly int Id;
    public readonly float PenWidth;

    public Stroke(int id, Color c, float penWidth)
    {
        points = new List<Point>();
        Id = id;
        Color = c; 
        PenWidth = penWidth;
        pen = new Pen(Color, PenWidth);
        pen.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;
        pen.StartCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;
    }

    public void Draw(Graphics graphics)
    {
        if ((points.Count < 2) || (graphics == null))
        {
            return;
        }

        graphics.DrawLines(pen, (Point[]) points.ToArray());
        //graphics.DrawCurve(pen, (Point[]) points.ToArray());
    }

    public void Add(Point pt)
    {
        if (points.Count > 0 && points[points.Count-1] == pt) return;
        points.Add(pt);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        pen.Dispose();
    }
}
```

used in the following manner

```
BufferedGraphics finalBuffer;
width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;

using (Graphics graphics = CreateGraphics())
{
    finalBuffer = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current.Allocate(graphics, new Rectangle(0,0,width,height));
}

// ...

Graphics g = finalBuffer.Graphics;
stroke.Draw(g);
stroke.Dispose();
```

where finalBuffer is what gets rendered to the e.Graphics inside OnPaint.

Comment: You need to set linejoins and miters of the pen you use. A good start is to set MiterLimit to Pen.width/2f; the Joins are a matter of taste, I prefer Round..

Comment: @TaW: okay, I will try it, although I wonder, what mathematical law for miter and line join might cause the appearance of the line end at the bottom right, especially if you look at the monotonous sequence of points in the list (last point is index 49). To me it just looks like garbage.

Comment: I tried pen.LineJoin = LineJoin.Round; pen.MiterLimit = 30.0f; and it works!!! Didn't know that, I've been thinking they default to something sensible. Thanks alot.